# How to run a timer every 12 hours (exceeding the max size of int) without an RTC?

Tags: arduino-nano, timers, rtc

I'm experimenting with a Nano, and trying to trigger an action around twice a day. I'm aware that it's not super accurate, but I don't really mind, as long as it's in the ballpark.

I've tried using the [SimpleTimer library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer) but I'm running into an issue because it takes milliseconds as an int, and 12 hours is 43200000 (larger than 32,767 max). Is there another library, or another technique I can use for this?

Comment: On the page you linked it takes a **long** as an argument, not an int: `int setInterval(long d, timer_callback f)`.

Comment: @NickGammon has it; there is no such limitation on the interval argument to setInterval() as "it takes milliseconds as an int". It takes a signed long, though it treats it internally as unsigned long, thus the max interval is over 49 *days*. Mark's answer will work, too, but is not actually necessary.

Comment: I better make it an actual answer then. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the timer for every hour, which is within the limit. In your action, keep a `static int`, initialized to zero, which you increment each time. When it `==12`, do the thing you want to do and reset your `int` back to zero.

Comment: dang that's simple and smart

Answer (score 5):

> I'm running into an issue because it takes milliseconds as an int ...

No it doesn't. Look at the function prototype:

---

```
int setInterval(long d, timer_callback f);
```

> Call function f every d milliseconds. The callback function must be declared as void f().

---

The interval `d` is a long. The `int` you see is the return value from the function, not the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 other options to the `setInterval()` function:

- `delay()` (blocking)
- `millis()` (non-blocking)

Both of these functions deal with an `unsigned long` which has 32 bits = (2^32)-1 = 4,294,967,295. Doing the sums (and considering that both are in milliseconds), this will last for 49 days and 17 hours.

1 second = 1000 milliseconds
1 minute = 60 seconds
1 hour = 60 minutes
12 hours = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 43,200,000

`delay(x)` will delay for x number of milliseconds.  The delay function is blocking, meaning that while it is running/delaying you can't do any other task. The code would be:

```
delay(43200000);
```

`millis()` on the other hand is non-blocking and returns the number of milliseconds since power-up.  This can be implemented with the following code:

```
#define TWELVE_HRS 43200000UL
unsigned long startTime;

setup()
{
  startTime = millis();
}

loop()
{
  if (millis() - startTime > TWELVE_HRS)
  {
    // Put your code that runs every 12 hours here

    startTime = millis();
  }
}
```